# postgresql+python: how to adapt for copy_from?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, sqlbulkcopy

What function can I use to adapt values for suitable use in a `COPY FROM` statement? I tried this `adapt` function:

```
from psycopg2.extensions import adapt
```

However, it gives the wrong thing for datetimes (appends `::timestsamp` to the string, postgres doesn't like it) and string (wraps them in single quotes, e.g. empty string is '', where it seems no quotes should be used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't just use `adapt` with `copy_from`.

`copy_from` expects a format different than SQL quoting.

For strings, I'd suggest to write your own `copy_adapt` function, which should escape tabs with `\t`, CR with `\r` and LF with `\n`.

Values for timestamp / date columns should be formatted (with strftime?) like the string which you see when you `SELECT now()` in Postgres.

Tuple elements should be saparated by tabs, and whole tuple finished with newline.

Comment: how do i know how to do things like convert datetimes into a format postgres accepts?